# Barcode no. need instead of sku code on order detail page and in voice

Tags: php, magento, frontend, magento-1.8

I am using magento 1.8.1 and I want some changes in admin panel. On order detail page I need to change sku code with barcode number, this barcode is is also need in invoice.

[image: changes]

I tried to change this in \app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\create\items with this code:

from:

```
<td class="first">
    <h5 class="title"><span id="order_item_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>_title"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></span></h5>
     <div>
          <strong><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('SKU') ?>:</strong>
                  <?php echo implode('<br />', Mage::helper('catalog')->splitSku($this->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()))); ?>
     </div>
```

to

```
<td class="first">
    <h5 class="title"><span id="order_item_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>_title"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></span></h5>
        <div>
            <strong><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('BARCODE') ?>:</strong>
                    <?php echo implode('<br />', Mage::helper('catalog')->splitBarcode($this->escapeHtml($_item->getBarcode()))); ?>
        </div>
```

but it is not working.
I also need to link the URL of product with product name.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the wrong location...
SKU comes from following path
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\items\column\name.phtml

Below is the code that needed to be modified

```
<h5 class="title"><span id="order_item_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>_title"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></span></h5>
<div><strong><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('SKU') ?>:</strong> <?php echo implode('<br />', Mage::helper('catalog')->splitSku($this->htmlEscape($this->getSku()))); ?></div>
```

Check this file..hope this will solve your problem

Comment: thanx for reply, can you please tell me how to edit this code to get barcode instead of sku?

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code into your local.xml file and you can then see template path hints in the Admin.  Granted this does not answer your question directly, however,it can help you find paths for other areas you may need to modify. Place the following all the way at the bottom of the file right before the closing   Just comment out or remove when done.

```
<websites>
    <admin>
        <dev>
            <debug>
                <template_hints>1</template_hints>
                <template_hints_blocks>1</template_hints_blocks>
            </debug>
        </dev>
    </admin>
</websites>
```